# i am trying to get message content. the code works in android 2.3.6 but crashes in 4.3

Tags: android-contentresolver

I am trying to get the content of a message. The following code works in Android 2.3.6 but crashes in 4.3.

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
receivedSmsCursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null, "date>?",
    new String[]{String.valueOf(today.getTimeInMillis())}, strOrder);
```

Comment: Can you provide more info (stack trace, etc.) about 'the crash'?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: When i calls following code, it shows the above error.                           msgbody1= receivedSmsCursor.getString(11);

Comment: What are the recquired permissions for conentResolvers in the Android version 4.3.I added the following permissions.                 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>